# Regular expression - Combine positive & negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I have basic knowledge in regex but not when it comes to lookaheads :-)
I have the following example:

```
<DIV style="overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px Solid rgb(192,192,192); position: absolute; left: 5821px; top: 22px; width: 1200px; height: 166px; "><DIV ID="s32" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 2px; width: 1185px; height: 162px; " >
    &#164;&lt;h1&gt;Some text within h1 tags.&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;<br>&#164;&#164;</DIV></DIV>

<DIV style="overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px Solid rgb(192,192,192); position: absolute; left: 5821px; top: 22px; width: 1200px; height: 166px; "><DIV ID="s33" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 2px; width: 1185px; height: 162px; " >
    &lt;h1&gt;Some text within h1 tags.&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;<br></DIV></DIV>

<DIV style="overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px Solid rgb(192,192,192); position: absolute; left: 5821px; top: 22px; width: 1200px; height: 166px; "><DIV ID="s32" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 2px; width: 1185px; height: 162px; " >
    &#164;&lt;h1&gt;Some text within h1 tags.&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;<br>&#164;&#164;</DIV></DIV>

<DIV style="overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px Solid rgb(192,192,192); position: absolute; left: 5821px; top: 22px; width: 1200px; height: 166px; "><DIV ID="s33" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 2px; width: 1185px; height: 162px; " >
    &lt;h1&gt;Some text within h1 tags.&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;<br></DIV></DIV>
```

I only want the text within div id s32 to match. I'm experimenting with a positive lookahead first to se if I can get at least that part right but while

```
(?<="s32".+)Some text
```

does work, this one

```
(?<="s32".+&#164;&#164;)Some text
```

doesn't...

I'm trying to understand why I don't get any match on this? With the above example I expected to get 3 matches. Once I understand this I could experiment with a negative lookahead that would then hopefully only give 2 matches (within the s32 `DIV`s).

Any advice and explanation is welcome as I'm currently a little bit lost :-)

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Variable length look behind is not handle by many regex flavour.

Comment: Hi Toto.

I'm using a tool called RegEx Tester V3.2.0.0 and only use this tool to perform search and replace actions on source code which I then export. If there is a better tool that you would recommend me to look at then I'm more than happy to do so.